# Is it possible to to only show Column row when using AG grid?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ag-grid

Im new to AG-Grid for JavaScript. I am wondering is it possible for me have a grid with only the column row displaying?? 
**Example of what I am trying to achieve:**
[image]

 
 I have attempted to make a grid with just the column row but I am greeted with a loading icon in the middle like so:

[image]

I am not sure why that popup is there as well as why it wont go away.
**code and snippet for the AG-Grid:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const gridOptions = {
      
           columnDefs: [
               // uses the default column properties
               { headerName: 'Col A', field: 'a'},
               // overrides the default with a number filter
               { headerName: 'Col B', field: 'b' },
               // overrides the default using a column type
               { headerName: 'Col C', field: 'c' },
               // overrides the default using a multiple column types
               { headerName: 'Col D', field: 'd'}
           ],

           defaultColDef:{
            width:100
        } 
        
    };
  var columnSelector  = document.querySelector('#gridColumnSelector');
  new agGrid.Grid(columnSelector,gridOptions);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/25.1.0/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="gridColumnSelector" 
                                        style="height: 100px; width: 400px;"
                                        class="ag-theme-balham col-md-3">

                                        </div>
```

also is it possible for me to make the div size the exact same size of the grid column so I don't have to declare a fixed height and width?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

After `columnDefs` add `rowData:[{'':''}, {'':''}, {'':''}, {'':''}],`.